# How create swipe-to-dismiss in android with delete btn by means of support library?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I need to add delete button into my RecyclerView. I have implemented onSwiped() method for deleting by swipe. But I want to show delete button on the item after user have swiped the item. How to do it? IMPORTANT: I use support library (com.android.support:recyclerview). Do not advice me others third-party libs.
Here my code for swap detecting.

```
    ItemTouchHelper swipeToDismissTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            // callback for drag-n-drop, false to skip this feature
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            // callback for swipe to dismiss, removing item from data and adapter
            list.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    swipeToDismissTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually implemented this use case but I have an idea that might push you in the right direction.

Firstly, you probably wanna draw some background, probably red :), with the delete icon while the user is swiping delete the row. For that you should use `onChildDraw` method, you can get the idea how to do that from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667171/android-swipe-to-delete-adding-an-undo-option)

What I should do then is NOT remove the item from `onSwiped` just mark it as deleted and make adapter draw the same thing (i.e. red background and white trashcan button). Actually remove it when the trashcan button is pressed.

Let me know if I need to elaborate on anything...

EDIT: I've implemented a sample project, not exactly what you need, but you should be able to figure out your use case. See this [blog post](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-no-3rd-party-lib-necessary-6bf6a6601214) and this [github repo](https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete).